# Flutter showModalBottomSheet is resetting the properties inside its widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using showModalBottomSheet for showing a form containing text fields, a map, and a button.

Method to show the Popup

```
 Future<Widget?> showSheet(BuildContext context, String title, List items,
    {double heightFactor = 0.8}) async {
  final cornerRadius = getProportionateScreenWidth(42);
  debugPrint("Corner Radius $cornerRadius");
  return await showModalBottomSheet(
    barrierColor: kGreyishPurpleHalfAlpha,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
      ),
    ),
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
      return PopupFormBody(
        title: title,
        items: items,
        heightFactor: heightFactor,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This is the body inside the sheet

```
class PopupFormBody extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List items;
  // final BuildContext context;
  final double heightFactor;

  const PopupFormBody(
      {required this.title, required this.items, required this.heightFactor});

  @override
  State<PopupFormBody> createState() => _PopupFormBodyState();
}

class _PopupFormBodyState extends State<PopupFormBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: widget.heightFactor,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 25, 0, 0),
              child: BottomSheetScrollDrawer(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 25),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.items.length + 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext cont, int index) {
                    debugPrint("Index $index");
                    if (index == 0) {
                      return headerTile(widget.title);
                    }
                    final item = widget.items[index - 1];
                    if (item is SurveyTextFieldModel) {
                      return textFieldTile(item);
                    } else if (item is MapDataModel) {
                      return mapTile();
                    } else if (item is ButtonData) {
                      return actionButton(item);
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text("Widget Missing"),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Methods associated with the form building

```
Widget headerTile(String title) {
  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, getProportionateScreenHeight(20), 0,
          getProportionateScreenHeight(23)),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: kRecentSurveyHeadlineStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget textFieldTile(SurveyTextFieldModel item) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 9,
      horizontal: 18,
    ),
    child: FormTextBox(
      validator: (dynamic value) {
        return item.validate() ? null : "This field is mandatory";
      },
      headerstring: item.textFieldName,
      onValueChanged: (String value) {
        item.userInputvalue = value;
      },
    ),
  );
}

Widget mapTile() {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(
          getProportionateScreenHeight(30),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(234),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 9,
      horizontal: 18,
    ),
    child: MapContainer(
      droppedPinLocation: (LatLng loc) {
        debugPrint(loc.toString());
      },
    ),
  );
}

Widget actionButton(ButtonData item) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 18),
    child: AppThemeButton(
      onClick: () {
        //TODO: Add action here
        debugPrint("$item button pressed!!");
      },
      childWidget: SizedBox(
        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(62),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            item.title,
            style: kButtonStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Map widget class

```
class MapContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  double? _latitude;
  double? _longitude;
  String locationMessage = kFetchingLocation;
  Marker? _marker;

  final LocationCallBack droppedPinLocation;

  MapContainer({required this.droppedPinLocation});

  @override
  State<MapContainer> createState() => _MapContainerState();
}

class _MapContainerState extends State<MapContainer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUserLocation();
  }

  fetchUserLocation() async {
    try {
      final LocationServiceable locationService = LocationService();
      LocationData? location = await locationService.getLocationData;
      widget._latitude = location?.latitude;
      widget._longitude = location?.longitude;
    } on LocationServiceDisabledException catch (_) {
      widget.locationMessage = kLocationAccessDenied;
    } finally {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    debugPrint("Did change dependencies");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint(
        "Drawing the map widget latitude ${widget._latitude} longitude ${widget._longitude}");
    return widget._latitude == null || widget._longitude == null
        ? Center(
            child: Text(widget.locationMessage),
          )
        : GoogleMap(
            markers:
                widget._marker != null ? <Marker>{widget._marker!} : <Marker>{},
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(widget._latitude!, widget._longitude!),
              zoom: 14.4746,
            ),
            onLongPress: (latlong) {
              const MarkerId markerId = MarkerId("tappedLocation");
              Marker marker = Marker(markerId: markerId, position: latlong);
              widget._marker = marker;
              widget.droppedPinLocation(latlong);
              debugPrint(
                  "Long press location ${latlong.latitude.toString()}, ${latlong.longitude.toString()}");
              setState(() {});
            },
          );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

When I open this popup MapContainer class fetches the user's current location and shows it on the map. I keep the lat and long values in the widget properties.

```
  double? _latitude;
  double? _longitude;
```

But whenever the keyboard comes up, the _latitude and _longitude values are set to null, and the build method of the MapContainer widget gets called.

I understand the reason behind calling the build method, but why does it remove the values set in _latitude and _longitude properties?

> initState or didChangeDependencies are not getting called while rebuilding.

Comment: You need to store the values of the Modal Bottom Sheet in a Provider and update the provider when the values of the modal bottom sheet changes. Then refill the widgets of the modal bottom sheets with their respective values when you decide to re-display the modal bottom sheet. ( Use the values in the provider as initializing values.)

Comment: @Georgina, Thank you. But why do the properties reset when the widget rebuilds?

Comment: The Modal Bottom sheets does not exist when it's off the screen.

Comment: It is not off the screen. The keyboard shows when I click on the text field inside the model bottom sheet.